# Ansible variable register task being skipped

Tags: variables, ansible

I am trying to come up with a playbook to determine the corresponding OSSEC release agent package to install on remote servers. The playbook first runs a shell command to determine the matching release RPM to install, but the variable register task is being skipped when I run the playbook in check mode.

```
tasks:

- name: Determine lateast OSSEC release RPM for CentOS version
  shell: curl -s https://www.atomicorp.com/channels/ossec/centos/$(cat /etc/redhat-release | awk '{print $3}' | cut -c1)/x86_64/RPMS/ | grep ossec-release | sed "s/'/ /g" | awk '{print $6}' | tail -1
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: ossec_release_rpm

- name: Install latest CentOS 6 OSSEC release RPM
  yum: name=https://www.atomicorp.com/channels/ossec/centos/6/x86_64/RPMS/{{ item }}
    state=present
  with_items: ossec_release_rpm.stdout

- name: Install ossec-hids-client
  yum: pkg=ossec-hids-client
    state=present
```

The output I am getting is the following. Specifically, the register task is being skipped and I can't seem to figure out why. The check completed but I'm fairly certain it will not work as it is.

```
PLAY [Install OSSEC client/server on Linux servers] *************************** 

GATHERING FACTS *************************************************************** 
ok: [dev-php1]

TASK: [Determine lateast OSSEC release RPM for CentOS version] **************** 
skipping: [dev-php1]

TASK: [Install latest CentOS 6 OSSEC release RPM] ***************************** 
changed: [dev-php1] => (item=ossec_release_rpm.stdout)

TASK: [Install ossec-hids-client] ********************************************* 
ok: [dev-php1]

TASK: [Check if client.keys exists] ******************************************* 
ok: [dev-php1]

TASK: [register client] ******************************************************* 
skipping: [dev-php1]

TASK: [Installing the ossec-agent.conf] *************************************** 
changed: [dev-php1]

NOTIFIED: [restart ossec-agent] *********************************************** 
changed: [dev-php1]

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************** 
dev-php1                   : ok=6    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Comment: re-run with `-vvvv` (verbose output) and share that. It may give some clues.

Comment: This is the only output with -vvvv

TASK: [Determine lateast OSSEC release RPM for CentOS version] **************** 
<dev-php1> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: root on PORT 22 TO dev-php1
skipping: [dev-php1]

Comment: hmm. I can't repro it locally- it runs for me. You'll have to break the command apart and debug it individually. Which isn't bad- you can read in redhat-release and use jinja filters to chop the string, you can save the output of the grep, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

`check_mode: no` can be used to have the shell task to be run when the `--check` option is passed to `ansible-playbook`.

See [Enabling or disabling check mode for tasks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_checkmode.html#id2) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. So I was running as a check and expecting the shell command to execute, which it would skip by default.